# Any issues using VS 2013 with TFS 2010

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013

I just wanted to see if anyone is using VS 2013 with TFS 2010 and if you have encountered any problems or gotchas? Also, on the build side, are any of you using VS 2013 side-by-side with VS 2012 and 2010 on your build boxes?

Comment: Just started using VS2013 with TFS 2010 and have not seen any issues so far. Haven't tried builds yet.

Comment: Thanks, mcknz. I have some devs that are using VS 2013 to connect to TFS 2010. Wasn't sure if there would be any issues.

Comment: UPDATE: Our devs have been using VS 2013 with TFS 2010 since I first posted this question. Thus far there haven't been any issues.

Comment: We have seen multiple issues. Folders get set to read only and TFS 2010 does not seem to have the ability to reset this when doing get latest version recursive from the client. Had to go through manually and reset them to get latest. We also have intermittent issues when two developers working on same file and the TFS does not ask if you want to merge on check in - almost lost some code from this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having issues, but I haven't nailed them down, so at the moment I'm just guessing that they are to do with a mix of VS 2013 and TFS 2010.

We've just gone through a process of upgrading a bunch of apps from .Net 1.1 to .Net 4. We used VS 2010 for this and executed the builds on TFS 2010. All was fine.

I am now using VS 2013 to do further development, but executing builds on TFS 2010 produces MSIs that successfully install, but blow up when run.

I haven't found anything else that has changed.

If I find out anything else, I'll update.

Comment: have you found the reason for your problems when you run your software? In our case our build machine  has TFS 2010, VS 2010 and VS 2015 installed in parallel. From the msbuild logs I can see that different compiler versions but same msbuild versions (4.0) are used even if I set VisualStudioVersion=10.0 via MsBuild arguments in the build definition. So I am concerned about different build results that may be the case since we installed VS 2015 on our build machine.